# best quality of recording synthesizer

Tags: audio-recording, ableton-live, piano, quality

Just trying to figure out the best way to get the most of out of my sound recording with my synthezier. I have a yamaha s90x which has such a great sound, which most of the qualities are lost recording it into my DAW. I have a line6  ux2 as my audio interface and am using ableton live 8 for my DAW. I am plugging my keyboard directly into my audio interface through the mono output. Any additonal suggestions would be great!!

Comment: in comparison to…? There's nothing wrong with a UX2 - it might not be megabucks, but it really isn't the problem. If you normally hear it through a 1969 Marshall Lead 50 through a Carlsboro 4x12, then what you're missing is the coloration that they provided.

Comment: It has such great sound when I connect it to my studio speakers. the sound easily clips out and loses a lot of quality when I hook it up to the computer & ux2

Comment: then turn it down. [edit] There really is nothing wrong with the UX2; i have one here. If it's hitting the stops, reduce the signal gain, just like any audio path. It has an old-style analog gain pot right on top for mic channels, though not for 'instrument' so turn down the keyboard's op gain, or plug it in the pad channel.

Comment: or [edit 2, as I haven't swapped my connections for years & just got a torch out...] or plug it in the back, not the front, that's for line-level, rather than guitar. Massive difference in levels between the 2.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output type on the piano vs. The input type of your interface. One of your comments above suggests an instrument/line level mismatch.

Let us know what you find for further suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the above, I don't think that your synth, or the interface is the issue.

Running a synth directly into an interface normally just gives a pretty boring copy of the original tone.  When I'm recording synths, I like to run them through an amp, any amp, and mic the output.

Depending on the desired result, running through a small bit of overdrive, or a hot tube pre-amp can add a lot of harmonic content.

On the resulting audio track, a little bit of chorus, or delay can really snap some life into your tone as well.

Comment: nah. it's plugged in the instrument jack, not line in - guarantee it ;-)

Comment: Yes, but is your keyboard instrument out or line out?

Comment: To derjur's point, you might try actually micing the piano since the speakers or room sound might be sweetening it up a bit.